# XML ASMX Service with 1 return value - not XDocument so How to Parse?

Tags: c#, silverlight, asmx

I am trying to return a value from an "XML Web Service" that I did not create.  It is an ASMX service with the following return:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
123
```

Where the value "123" varies depending on the parameters I feed the service.  My question is, in C# (Silverlight), how can I parse this value?

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(service);
```

I do not see an easy way to get to the value.

Comment: The data sample you provided is not valid xml. Is it exactly how it looks?

Comment: It is, that's why I'm having a difficult time parsing out the value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Saunders said, this is not XML, so you can't parse it as one.

If the format is always this simple, just get the second line and use that.

**EDIT:**

If it's just the second line you want to get, you can use something like:

```
string result = downloaded.Split('\n')[1];
```

Comment: I agree.  I am not the creator of this "XML Web Service".  How would I go about getting the value then?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's not XML, so there's no way to parse it as XML.

Comment: I agree.  I am not the creator of this "XML Web Service".  How would I go about getting the value then?  Thanks.

Comment: Do make sure the creators of the "XML" know it's not XML. Tell them you'll make it work anyway, but make sure they know. Ask them to open it as XML in an XML editor if they don't believe you.